# rosmake and roscreate-pkg not responding

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm pretty new to ROS so please excuse me if I forget to mention stuff.
I was working on a project today. I think it doesn't matter what it was about. At some point when I was working on a .cpp file I tried to rosmake it, as I have done before dozens of times. At this time, however, nothing happend. I waited for a couple of minutes without anything changing.
After that couple of minutes I used ctrl+c to terminate rosmake.
This is what was printed in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/roscreate-pkg", line 35, in <module>
  roscreate.roscreatepkg.roscreatepkg_main()
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roscreate/roscreatepkg.py", line 117, in roscreatepkg_main
  rospack.get_path(d)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 147, in get_path
  self._update_location_cache()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 130, in _update_location_cache
  list_by_path(self._manifest_name, path, cache)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 56, in list_by_path
  for d, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True, followlinks=True):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
  for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
  for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
  for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
  for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
  for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 276, in walk
  names = listdir(top)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

It somehow seems that it freezes for some reason.

I have no idea what any of this means. And I unsuccessfully googled this error. When I try to run roscreate-pkg or roswtf I get similar results. rosrun however seems to work.

Thanks for your help!

Cheers,
Lukas

edit: The output is from roscreate-pkg!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45653/rosmake-and-roscreate-pkg-not-responding/) by [Lukas](https://answers.ros.org/users/3366/lukas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lukas](https://answers.ros.org/users/3366/lukas/) on 2012-10-11**:
I just tried it again and now it works. I rebooted after this problem occurred, but it didn't help. Apparently I needed to sleep over it and also let the computer sleep... Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems from the stack trace that PYTHON just had to crawl a *HUGE* lot of files in your folder, which takes time.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2